# why do I have a syswow64 folder on my windows 7 x64 machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have an error coming up when I try to launch an application inside a virtualbox machine running a 64-bit version of windows 7 ultimate
now in order to fix that error for another application unrelated to this one it has been suggested to (re)place certain dll files in either the syswow64 folder for 32-bit systems or the system32 folder in 64-bit systems

now I'm a bit confused as to why I have both these folders on my system
I would be happy if someone could break it down for me in a short and easy sentence without sending me on a nirvana on this silly thing called the google

Comment: Because you are supposed to have it?

Answer (score 1):

System32 is used to store 64bit programs. SysWoW64 is used to store 32bit programs.

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to name it *binaries* instead of *programs* or *modules*? This is also the place for 32-bit DLLs.